# GPU support for task currently within AWS-Fargate cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

My main objective is to utilize GPU for one of our existing task being deployed through Fargate.

We have existing load balancers for our staging and production environments.

Currently we have two ECS Fargate clusters which deploy Fargate serverless tasks.

*We want to be able to deploy one of our existing fargate tasks with GPU, but because [fargate doesn't support GPU](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/88), we need to configure an EC2 task.*

To do this, I believe we need to create EC2 auto-scaling groups associated with both the staging and production environments that allow for deploying an EC2 instances with a GPU through ECS.

**I'm unsure whether or not we need to create a new cluster to house the EC2 task, or if we can put the EC2 task in our existing clusters (can you mix Fargate and EC2 like this?).**

We're using Terraform for Infrastructure as code.
Any AWS documentation or relevant Terraform docs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely mix Fargate and EC2 tasks in the same cluster. Recommended checking out Capacity Providers for this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html

Comment: In short, add capacity to your ECS cluster so it has a GPU EC2 instance. Be sure to choose an "ECS Optimized AMI" as those will have NVIDIA/CUDA drivers/SDKs installed for Docker to be able to use the GPU. Then read this documentation thoroughly, as there are some env vars and bootstrapping you need to have set in the instance, as well as some modifications for the task placement strategy:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-gpu.html#ecs-gpu-specifying